# placing labels on canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a scrollable table and the interface below looks almost like what I want. What still annnoys me though is that I have to pass in a parameter column_width. I'd rather divide my canvas into equidistant columns. The need to determine the width would than be redundant.

```
import tkinter as tk

class ScrollableTable:
    def __init__(self, frame, rows, columns, column_width):
        self.frame = frame

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame, width= self.frame.winfo_reqwidth(), height=frame.winfo_reqheight())
        # self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, 0, 100000))
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.vbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient='vertical', command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.vbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.vbar.set)

        self.initialize_table(rows, columns, column_width)

    def initialize_table(self, rows, columns, column_width):

        for i in range(rows):
            column_cor = 0
            row_cor = row_cor + label.winfo_reqheight() if i != 0 else 0

            for j in range(columns):
                label = tk.Label(self.canvas, relief = 'solid', width = column_width)
                column_cor = column_cor + label.winfo_reqwidth() if j != 0 else label.winfo_reqwidth() / 2
                row_cor = row_cor  if i != 0 else label.winfo_reqheight() / 2
                self.canvas.create_window(column_cor, row_cor, window=label)

        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, 0, label.winfo_reqheight()*rows))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = tk.Frame(root, width = 600, height = 400, relief = 'solid')
    frame.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
    ScrollableTable(frame, rows = 100, columns = 4, column_width = 20)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you using a canvas instead of a  frame? Are you needing to be able to scroll the canvas? Have you read the documentation on `grid` and tried some simple examples? A question you asked a couple days ago implied you want to create a scrollable table. Is this question related to that?

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry for the late reply. I edited the orginal post so you can see the full code. What I have right now is pretty neat but it still annoys me that I haven't found a way to subdivide the canvas (I believe it's the canvas not the frame) in equidistant columns. I have to pass an additional parameter colum_width which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You are simulating a grid by placing widgets at specific coordinates. If you're going to use that technique, it is up to you to compute the coordinates correctly.

Comment: @BryanOakley the coordinates are not the problem. They're correct. What I need to know: real_label_width = canvas_widht/number_of_columns. The problem is label.configure(width = real_label_width) obviously doesn't work but so I need to know some scaling fator which depends on the font size of the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the width of the label when you add it to the canvas with the `create_window` method. Simply divide the canvas width by the number of columns, and use that value to set the width of each column.

For example, here's your `initialize_table` method with the following changes:

- I removed the `column_width` parameter and replaced it with a calculation.
- I removed the `width` parameter when creating the label
- I added the `width` parameter when calling `create_window`
- I moved the computation of `column_cor` after calling `create_window` 
  so that the first cell is at the left margin
- I used the `anchor` option to `create_window` so that the cells start
  in the upper-left corner of the canvas.

---

```
def initialize_table(self, rows, columns):

    column_width = int(self.canvas.winfo_reqwidth()/columns)
    for i in range(rows):
        column_cor = 0
        row_cor = row_cor + label.winfo_reqheight() if i != 0 else 0

        for j in range(columns):
            label = tk.Label(self.canvas, relief = 'solid')
            row_cor = row_cor  if i != 0 else label.winfo_reqheight() / 2
            self.canvas.create_window(column_cor, row_cor, window=label, width=column_width, anchor="nw")
            column_cor = column_cor + column_width

    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, 0, label.winfo_reqheight()*rows))
```